# Select Condition Based on Multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a Table Like this:

```
TableA
----------------------------
ID   - Name  - PatID
1       A         10
2       B         10
3       A         11
4       A         12
5       B         13
```

I want to select All Such `PatID` Which has `Name=A and Name = B`.

So i should only get `10` as result.

What should be query for this?

Comment: What do you mean 'i should only get 10 as result'? Do you expect 10 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the following query to get the result:

```
select patid
from tablea
where name in ('A', 'B')
group by patid
having count(distinct name) = 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93933/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you need information from the A group and the B group you could also do it like this:

```
SELECT AGroup.ID AS AId, BGroup.ID AS BId
FROM TableA AGroup
JOIN TableB BGroup
    ON AGroup.Name = 'A'
    AND BGroup.Name = 'B'
    AND AGroup.PatID = BGroup.PatID
```

This also retains duplicates if you have more than one entry, for Name = A and PatID = 10 for example.